# Unknown coordinate system for the Netherlands

Tags: coordinate-system, netherlands

I have a table with x and y coordinates. It is mentioned that coordinates in "RD Bessel" system. I couldn't find it in ArcGIS and QGIS. Also no info on google?

Comment: There are 1 projected and 4 geographic Bessel coordinate reference systems included in ArcGIS 10.4. Have you tried those? Type 'bessel' in the coordinate reference search box. Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_ellipsoid. Also, I see that there are two projections called "RD Old" and "RD New", both of which use the Bessel_1841 spheroid.

Comment: I saw Bessel 1841. Is it RD?

Comment: Yes, the RD systems are based on a geographic coordinate reference system (datum) that uses the Bessel 1841 ellipsoid.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is that you're looking for the "RD New" projection, or possibly "RD Old". In ArcGIS, it is found under: Projected Coordinate Systems -> National Grids -> Europe -> RD New. Both "RD New" and "RD Old" use the [Bessel Spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_ellipsoid).

More information:

- https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijksdriehoeksco%C3%B6rdinaten
- https://epsg.io/28992